# Too many nested loops in excel

Tags: excel, loops, nested

I have a code that has way too many nested statements

Basically I have 82 counties and need to break up the counties by district (1-7)
The list I am searching through is over 6000. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Hova

`=IF(C2=1,7,IF(C2=2,1,IF(C2=3,7, IF(C2=2,4,2, IF(C2=2,5,2 ,IF(C2=2,6,3, IF(C2=2,7,2,IF(C2=2,8,2,IF(C2=2,9,1,IF(C2=2,10,1,IF(C2=2,11,3,IF(C2=2,12,6,IF(C2=2,13,1,IF(C2=2,14,2,IF(C2=2,15,3,IF(C2=2,16,7,IF(C2=2,17,2,IF(C2=2,18,6,IF(C2=2,19,7,IF(C2=2,20,6,IF(C2=2,21,6,IF(C2=2,22,2,IF(C2=2,23,6,IF(C2=2,24,6,IF(C2=2,25,5,IF(C2=2,26,3,IF(C2=2,27,3,IF(C2=2,28,3,IF(C2=2,29,1,IF(C2=2,30,6,IF(C2=2,31,6,IF(C2=2,32,3,IF(C2=2,33,7,IF(C2=2,34,6,IF(C2=2,35,5,IF(C2=2,36,2,IF(C2=2,37,6,IF(C2=2,38,5,IF(C2=2,39,7,IF(C2=2,40,5,IF(C2=2,41,1,IF(C2=2,42,2,IF(C2=2,43,7,IF(C2=2,44,1,IF(C2=2,45,5,IF(C2=2,46,7,IF(C2=2,47,2,IF(C2=2,48,1,IF(C2=2,49,2,IF(C2=2,50,5,IF(C2=2,51,5,IF(C2=2,52,5,IF(C2=2,53,1,IF(C2=2,54,2,IF(C2=2,55,6,IF(C2=2,57,7,IF(C2=2,58,1,IF(C2=2,59,1,IF(C2=2,60,2,IF(C2=2,61,5,IF(C2=2,62,5,IF(C2=2,63,3,IF(C2=2,64,7,IF(C2=2,65,7,IF(C2=2,66,6,IF(C2=2,67,3,IF(C2=2,68,2,IF(C2=2,69,2,IF(C2=2,70,1,IF(C2=2,71,1,IF(C2=2,72,2,IF(C2=2,73,1,IF(C2=2,74,7,IF(C2=2,75,3,IF(C2=2,75,3,IF(C2=2,76,3,IF(C2=2,77,6,IF(C2=2,78,1,IF(C2=2,79,7,IF(C2=2,80,1,IF(C2=2,81,2,IF(C2=2,82,3,0))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))`

Comment: I would add another sheet and map the counties to a district then do a VLOOKUP on the county number.  That way if a county ever changes districts you only have to change it in one spot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

```
=vlookup(lookupValue, tableArray, column#inTableToReturn, rangelookup?)
```

Where rangelookup? should be false if you require an exact match

tableArray should be a range somewhere (possibly its own sheet) that has a column of every country and in the next column, which district you want to return.

If you have two columns (country and district), then column# would be 2.